# Changing the site URL broke my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, url

My wordpress kept using the domain as my domain IP address and not my http://www.DestinyKingPhotography.com address. That being said I changed it in the general settings and ended up breaking my site. I tried going to the functions.php option and added

update_option('siteurl','http://www.DestinyKingPhotography.com');
update_option('home','http://www.DestinyKingPhotography.com');

Yet this doesn't work. I know this is a user error but I am struggle to figure this out. I have already been to this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL but I still am unable to figure it out.

Please help me out I am so lost.

Thank you

Destiny King

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use FTP to replace the functions.php file with a good copy and without the IP change function. See [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and [FTP Clients « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients).

Second, add these two lines to your wp-config.php a few lines of white space below the opening `<?php` to change back to the IP:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://your-ip-address');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-ip-address');
```

After your site is back up with the IP, use [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to do a correct find/replace in the whole database, after you do a database backup from Bluehost's Cpanel. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database

If the site doesn't come back up with the lines above in wp-config.php, go ahead and use the Interconnect script to change them in the whole database, but backup your database first.

Answer (score 0):

That's what is referred to as the "white screen of death." There are lots of troubleshooting guides out there. [Here's the one from the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors)

Since you were editing `functions.php`, that is probably the root cause. If you can restore the old file from a backup, do it.

In my case, it's almost always been caused by extra whitespace after a `?>`. If you don't have a backup, you might want to remove the closing `?>` tag from it. [It isn't needed.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me thank you so much.

I had made the same lethal error and used the `update_option` in "functions.php".

The site completely broke.

I went into my "wp-config.php" and changed the address back to my subdirectory:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://your-ip-address/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-ip-address/wordpress');
```